# How to restrict the user from viewing comments but with option to write comments?

Tags: plugins, customization

How to restrict the user from viewing comments. the regular user can only write comments but only the administrator can see all the comments?

if is there any plugin or other solution I'll be grateful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't ask for plugins recommendations here since that is considered offtopic.

That being said, what you can do is to modify the `comments.php` file of your theme, I recommend you to use a **childtheme**, in that file you will locate where the comments are being shown and you will enclose it on:

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
    // comments, only admins or editors can read
<?php } ?>
```